# One pgfplot per page in single PDF file

Tags: graphics, pgfplots

I'd like to reduce my redundancy when making plots with [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). I want to have a single PDF file, such that I can include them on a per-page basis with [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

The `multi` class option for the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class (the class I'm writing my plots with) looks promising, but instead of treating the plot as a single *block*, `multi` treats the plot as a single *page*. (which I assume is `multi`'s purpose).

As an example, I'd like to achieve a result similar to [this PDF file](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/dda/source/figs.pdf), but with pgfplots (from ["A Course on Deterministic Distributed Algorithms"](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/dda/) by [Jukka Suomela](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/)).

**MWE Code:**

```
% Remove the `multi` option and the code in between the
% comment bars to achieve the `standalone` default output.
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

**MWE Output:**

[image: mwe output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

rather than `multi` then you get one plot per page.

You might also be interested in

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
```